# Loading columns for an ExtJS dynamically

Tags: extjs

I am having trouble figuring out what I need to do to load the columns for an ExtJS grid dynamically.  I want to be able to send the column headers as JSON and have the grid take that and generate the columns needed.

More specifically, I am wanting to do this using the GroupingHeader plugin, but I really just want to figure out how to do it without the added complexity of the GroupingHeader plugin first and then I can tackle that problem :)

Here is some sample JSON data that I have for the column headers:

```
[
    {
        "run_id":"110207gad",
        "iterations":[
            "1_14",
            "2_16",
            "3_18",
            "4_20",
            "5_22"
        ]
    },{
        "run_id":"110207gae",
        "iterations":[
            "1_14",
            "2_16",
            "3_18",
            "4_20",
            "5_22"
        ]
    }
]
```

This is the data that I would need to do the grouping, where the `run_id` would be the grouped header and the `iterations` would be the column headers.  Right now, I'm happy just getting the `iterations` to show up as columns and then I can work on getting the grouping to work.

If anyone could point me in the right direction or give me some hints on where to begin, that would be extremely helpful!  I'm not beyond figuring this out on my own, but I just need a little bump to get started because I can't seem to figure out from looking at the ExtJS examples and doing some Google searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you look at the source code of the ExtJS example.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/array-grid.js

It should give you a fair amount of information to get started.

You can start from this format, pass it from your server:

`{"success":true,"message":"Loaded data","data":[{"run_id":1,"iterations":"1"},{"run_id":2,"iterations":"2"},{"run_id":3,"iterations":"3"}]}`

Then your reader will look like this:

```
var reader = new Ext.data.JsonReader({
    totalProperty: 'total',
    successProperty: 'success',
    idProperty: 'run_id',
    root: 'data',
    messageProperty: 'message'  
}, [
    {name: 'run_id'},
    {name: 'iterations', allowBlank: false}
]);
```

Comment: This example shows how to create a simple grid without loading the data from the server. To load the data from the server, you need `Ext.data.JsonStore` and `Ext.data.JsonReader`. You can look at the documentation http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/ under the section Ext > data > JSONStore . Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm able to create one using an array, but it's not very elegant to do this by injecting PHP code into JavaScript to "build" the array. I've been doing quite a bit of messing around with the JSONStore example and just don't really understand how my JSON data needs to be formatted to make it work like I want to dynamically generate the columns.  Thanks for the information though!

Comment: @Jared I updated the answer with some more tips on defining your structure, a code using JSON can be checked in this example. Using Firebug you can see the JSON string passed from the server. http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/writer/writer.js